# Binding a null variable in a PreparedStatement

Tags: java, jdbc, null

I swear this used to work, but it's not in this case.  I'm trying to match col1, col2 and col3, even if one or more of them is null.  I know that in some languages I've had to resort to circumlocutions like `((? is null AND col1 is null) OR col1 = ?)`.  Is that required here?

```
        PreparedStatement selStmt = getConn().prepareStatement(
                "SELECT     * " +
                "FROM       tbl1 " +
                "WHERE      col1 = ? AND col2 = ? and col3 = ?");
        try
        {
            int col = 1;
            setInt(selStmt, col++, col1);
            setInt(selStmt, col++, col2);
            setInt(selStmt, col++, col3);
            ResultSet rs = selStmt.executeQuery();
            try
            {
                while (rs.next())
                {
                   // process row
                }
            }
            finally
            {
                rs.close();
            }
        }
        finally
        {
            selStmt.close();
        }

   // Does the equivalient of stmt.setInt(col, i) but preserves nullness.
    protected  static void setInt(PreparedStatement stmt, int col, Integer i)
    throws SQLException
    {
        if (i == null)
            stmt.setNull(col, java.sql.Types.INTEGER);
        else
            stmt.setInt(col, i);
    }
```

Comment: See also http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Null_%28SQL%29#Three-valued_logic_.283VL.29

Answer (score 11, accepted):

This may depend on the JDBC driver, but for the most part, yes, you would need to use the more extended form you show above.

JDBC prepared statements are usually relatively thin wrappers around a native implementation of a parameterized query, i.e., the query with ? in place of parameters are passed to the query compiler and compiled, so, later, when you call stmt.executeQuery(), the statement cannot be adjust from a  `column = ?` to `column IS NULL`. This isn't so much a limitation of JDBC as it [the semantics of NULL in SQL](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Null_(SQL)). For SQL `x = NULL` is undefined as is `x <> NULL`.

That said, some JDBC drivers may violate the notion of `NULL`-ity in SQL and allow setNull() to transform the statement from `= ?` to `IS NULL` this would be highly non-standard behavior (though it could be easily accomplished by writing some sort of query pre-processing method).

Answer (score 3):

What database are you using?

But at least with Oracle, equality (and inequality) never matches NULL, you have to write IS NOT NULL.

Answer (score 1):

Generally something being equal to NULL is always false (even NULL, so `SELECT * FROM tbl WHERE NULL=NULL;` will be an empty set), so you probably do need to do it the long way if you want to accept null equality like that

Comment: @michael-mrozek `WHERE NULL = NULL` actually returns `NULL`. Thus, for example, `SELECT * FROM tbl WHERE NOT (NULL = NULL)` also results in an empty set.

Answer (score 0):

I know that is too late perhaps, but just for the sake of it a hack for Oracle which seems to me working:

SQL:

```
SELECT.....FROM....WHERE NVL(CUST_ID,0)=? AND NVL(vendor_id,0)=?
```

And in the code where you do the jdbc call something like this:

```
pstmt.setString(1, ( xxo.getCustId().equals("")) ? "0":xxo.getCustId());
pstmt.setString(2, ( xxo.getVendId().equals("")) ? "0":xxo.getVendId());
rs = pstmt.executeQuery();
```

Comment: Only works if you absolutely positively know that "0" is not a valid string in the column.

Comment: Yes I agree. I use it in columns where I expect data and 0 is not one of it and certainly null is not an option as well. It is a good trick I think....

Comment: Why not  "CUST_ID = ? OR (? IS NULL AND CUST_ID IS NULL)" ?